# Hover on a lozange Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow, css-transitions

I have a problème with Internet Explorer (not Microsoft Edge).

This is my HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="extension/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/deco.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bloc_principal_losange">
        <div id="fond">
            <i class="valign-helper"></i>
            <h2>Contenu</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS code

```css
#bloc_principal_losange{
    position:relative;
    margin:150px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:1.8em;
    cursor:pointer;
}
 
#fond{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:284px;
    height:284px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:-41px;
    margin-top:-41px;
    background:url('../img/face-service.jpg');
}
 
.valign-helper{
    width:0;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
.valign-helper + *{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The thing is, i try to do a link who's only clickable on the lozenge. But doesn't work on Internet Explorer (i reapeat, Internet Explorer non Microsoft Edge). Even if we don't see the square because having an overflow:hidden. We can click out of the lozenge.

If you don't see what i want to say, u can use this code on Chrome and IE and you will see the difference